# "@" symbol in password in applescript

Tags: applescript

I am using an applescript to mount a users home folder. However, when I use a password with a "@" symbol the script fails since the "@" symbol is also the separator between the password and servername? Anyway around this outside of changing the password?

Thanks

Here is the script:

```
display dialog "Please enter your username" default answer ""
set the user_name to the text returned of the result

display dialog "Please enter your password" default answer "" with hidden answer
set pass_word to the text returned of the result

set server_name to "servername"
set share_name to "sharename"
mount volume "smb://" & user_name & ":" & pass_word & "@" & server_name & "/" & share_name & "/" & user_name
```

Comment: instead of @ use % for it

Comment: Note that on most Unices, you don't want to put passwords in command lines because they can then be viewed with `ps` and the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using the in-line form to give the username and password, you can specify them as parameters for the `mount volume` command. Changing the final line to the following will work with passwords with special characters:

```
mount volume "smb://" & server_name & "/" & share_name & "/" & user_name as user name user_name with password pass_word
```